# Get dimensions of text block via JavaScript, not the size of container's `getBoundingClientRect`

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I want to get the size of text inside a container. Let's consider general case when the container has padding and border.

The problem is that `getBoundingClientRect` returns the size of text PLUS left border and padding, in case the text overflows. Otherwise it returns just the size of border box of the container.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can get the width if you create a placeholder div with all of the same text formatting options and find it's width.

For instance, I will create a div with the class `.hidden` that has the same attributes as the original div.

```
div.container
{
    font-size: 16px;
}

div.hidden
{
    font-size: 16px;
    display: none;
}
```

Then, using jQuery, copy the contents of `.container` to `.hidden` and find the width of `.hidden`:

```
$(function(){

    $("div.container").each(function(){
   
        $("body").append("<div class='hidden'>"+$(this).html()+"</div>");
        var width = $("div.hidden").width();
        $("div.width").html("Actual width: "+width+"px");
        $("div.hidden").remove();
    
    });

});
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rg4n8qpu/1)

Answer (score 2):

Interesting! You could use javascript to clone the text inside of an empty element offscreen that has 0 padding/margin/border. Then you could get the width of that element.

```js
var txt = document.getElementById('fixed').innerHTML,
    clone = document.getElementById('clone');

clone.innerHTML = txt;

var width = clone.offsetWidth;

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = width;
```

```css
#fixed {
    width: 8em;
    height: 8em;
    border: .5em solid red;
}

#clone { 
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  position: fixed;
  left: -9999px;
}
```

```html
<div id="fixed">asdfkjahsdflkahjsdflkjhasdljfhalsdkjfhalsdkjfhalsdkjfhalksdhjflasd</div>
<div id="clone"></div>

Width of text: <span id="output"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

People who had answered here came with a brilliant idea of wrapping the text into a `<div>` having zero `margin`, `border` and `padding`;

I just developed the idea further. I place the div inside the container, making the text have exactly the same style as it had without wrapper.

### [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/krngwp5e/5/)

This solution will work almost everywhere. It can be broken by not very encouraged way of writing CSS, like

```
.container div b {
    padding: 5px;       /* firing only when test is run */
}
```

If you do not code CSS in you project like that, you are the lucky one to use my snippet )